# M2M links in CouchDB with non-primary keys

Tags: couchdb

I have a bunch of "meeting" documents and a bunch "user" documents. A
user may have multiple emails and a meeting may be between multiple
people identified by emails.

I need to lookup users by meeting ID and meeting by user ID by way of
the emails.

My documents look like this right now:

```
{
  "type": "meeting"
  "_id": "MEETINGID",
  "emails": ["test1@example.com", "test2@example.com"]
  // Lots of others things
}

{
  "type": "user",
  "_id": "USERID",
  "emails": ["a@example.com", "test1@example.com"]
  // Lots of others things
}
```

I need to keep them linked via email.

But I could certainly split them out like this if it would help:

```
{
  "type": "user",
  "_id": "USERID",
  // Lots of others things
}

{
  "type": "user-email",
  "_id": "USERID",
  "email": "a@example.com"
}

{
  "type": "user-email",
  "_id": "USERID",
  "email": "test1@example.com"
}
```

I need views that produce something like this:

```
{
  "key": "MEETING",
  "document": {"_id": "USERID"}
}


{
  "key": "USERID",
  "document": {"_id": "MEETINGID"}
}
```

Is this going to be possible? I have a horrible feeling I'm going to
be making load of queries to do this :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple answer is "you can't" unfortunately. CouchDB doesn't allow stuff like that.

Answer (score 0):

you can write a map like

```
"meetingByEmail": 
  function (doc) {
    if(doc.type=="meeting") {
      for (var curEmail in doc.emails) {
        emit (doc.emails[curEmail],null);
      }
    }
  }
```

call:

```
 _view/byEmail?key="test1@example.com":
```

Result:

```
{"total_rows":4,"offset":0,"rows":[
{"id":"f2338c8e69d1da02c94a2104b6000e77","key":"test1@example.com","value":null},
{"id":"f2338c8e69d1da02c94a2104b6000e88","key":"test1@example.com","value":null}
]}
```

(f2338c8e69d1da02c94a2104b6000e77 is ID from a Meeting, user test1 has joined two meetings)

vice versa (for user)

```
function(doc) {
  if(doc.type=="user") {
    for (var curEmail in doc.emails) {
      emit (doc.emails[curEmail],null);
    }
  }
}
```

the call

```
user/_view/byEmail?key="test1@example.com"
```

result:

```
{"total_rows":2,"offset":1,"rows":[
{"id":"user1","key":"test1@example.com","value":null}
]}
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer! Unfortunately while that lets me retrieve either meeting or user by email but it doesn't help retrieving meeting by user id or user by meeting id. The solution I have now uses what you've suggested here and involves a separate query for each address which isn't great.

Comment: okay, in this case you have to change "emails[" to "user[" with {userId:..,email:}] field , and if a user changes his (her) email, query all meeting with that user_id and change the user data. with that setup you can write a view that has two emits.. user.id and user.email .. and you receive the meeting. the second (user by meeting) is easy.. just GET the meetingID and you have all users..

Comment: Those are not quite the semantics I want though. Both of the the types can exist independently of each other, so a meeting can exist with emails that are not in a user and vice versa. The link should also be on email field, so if the list of emails associated with a document changes so does the link. I know I *could* do this by running processes that check and patch up everything whenever anything changes, but that seems like such a brittle way to do things.